# Managing multiple apps with pyramid

Tags: python, django, pyramid

I recently moved from Django to Pyramid because my traffic increased and I needed a better scalable framework.

My django project was structured in this way:

- user(app): views, models, forms, templates, etc
- download (app): views, models, forms, templates, etc
- store (app): views, models, forms, templates, etc
- static: all the static files (images, css, etc..) in the same folder because they are shared between the applications

Now I'm trying to replicate the same project structure with Pyramid, but every application has its own static-files folder.
I need to create a common static folder.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: It's not clear how "every application has its own static-files folder" with Pyramid because there are no "pluggable applications" in Pyramid in Django-sense. Are you assembling your app from separate Pyramid WSGI apps, or by including their configs into a "super-app" or somehow else? At any rate, it's not cleat what's preventing you from having a common  static folder.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [config.include()](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/advconfig.html#including-configuration-from-external-sources) method to emulate your Django applications.

Shared static folder can be easily done using static views, that can point to any folder in the file system.  See [Serving Static Assets](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/assets.html#serving-static-assets) in the documentation.